# Angular Filter Returns Unusual Results

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a filter that I use to average a column of data on a table:

```
app.filter('avgByKey', function () {
return function (data, key) {
    if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
        return 0;
    }
    var total = 0
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        total += data[i][key];
    }
    var avg = total / data.length;
    avg = Math.round(avg);
    return parseInt(avg);
}
```

})

I use it like so in my HTML:

```
{{y.yearDetails|avgByKey:'" + $scope.columns[i].vchAssociatedDetailColumn + "'}}
```

The filter works as expected until I change the data in one of the cells.  If I change a number in one of the cells it returns a number like "14578993057614092" as the average.  I have an almost identical filter that I use on the same table to get the sum of the columns:

```
app.filter('sumByKey', function() {
return function (data, key) {
    if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
        return 0;
    }

    var sum = 0;
    for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        //sum += parseFloat(data[i][key]);
        sum += Math.round((data[i][key]) * 100)/100;
    }
    if (sum < 1) {
        return parseFloat(sum.toPrecision(2));

    }
    else {
        return sum;

    }
};
```

});

It works perfectly even when I change a number in one of the cells. If I refresh the page after I change one of the numbers in the cell with the average filter, the filter then shows the "correct" answer, but I must refresh the page to get it. Can anyone tell me why my average is filter is exhibiting this behavior and how I can fix it?

Here is a Plunker that shows what happens: [Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/uyQBNabfVMQCXgKVpQmi?p=preview)

Comment: can you provide some HTML code or JsFiddle to understand scenario better?

Comment: I have added a Plunker to demonstrate the behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use - total += `parseInt`(data[i][key]); will solve this issue.

```
app.filter('avgByKey', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
            return 0;
        }
        var total = 0
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            total += parseInt(data[i][key]);
        }
        var avg = total / data.length;
        avg = Math.round(avg);
        return parseInt(avg);
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  That did it.

Comment: My pleasure to help!

Answer (score 0):

Your inputs are being parsed into string values and so not being added up in the way you expect.

Instead they are being concatenated into a really long string of numbers such as `'3' + '5' + '7' = '357'`

You need to parse them as numbers using `parseInt()`.

```
app.filter('avgByKey', function () {
    return function (data, key) {
        if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
            return 0;
        }
        var total = 0
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            total += parseInt(data[i][key]);
        }
        var avg = total / data.length;
        avg = Math.round(avg);
        return parseInt(avg);
    }
});
```